# Consistent header error in React/HTML code

Tags: html, reactjs, tags

I'm using React, and I can't figure out where the error in this code is. Starting on line 7, it says the div has no closing tag. Then, I get the same error, but on lines 13, 14, 91, 93, 94 and 101. I'm doing a Hackathon, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
import React from "react"
import Navbar from "./navbar"
// import Footer from "./footer"

function Questions() {
    return (
     <div>
        {/* <!-- Q&A PAGE --> */}
    
        {/* <!-- Navigation Bar --> */}
        <Navbar/> 
    
    <div class="container">
      <footer class="py-3 my-4">
        <ul class="nav justify-content-center border-bottom pb-3 mb-3">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="{{ url_for('home')}}" class="nav-link px-2 text-body-secondary" 
    <form action="#" method = "post">

      {/* <!-- Asks for name of the person --> */}
      <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> name </p>
      <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="text" name = "name"> </input> </p>


      <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> Race </p>
        <ul>
          <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "race" value = "Black"> Black </input> </p>
          <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "race" value =  "East_Asian"> East Asian </input> </p>
          <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "race" value = "Latinx"> Latinx </input> </p>
          <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "race" value = "South_Asian"> South Asian </input> </p>
          <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "race" value = "South_Asian"> South Asian </input> </p>
          <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "race" value = "White"> White </input> </p>
        </ul>

        <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> Gender </p>
        <ul>
          <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "gender" value = "Male"> Male </input> </p>
          <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "gender" value = "Female"> Female </input> </p>
          <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "gender" value = "Non-binary"> Non-binary </input> </p>
        </ul>

        <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> Sexuality </p>
        <ul>
          <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "sexuality" value = "Gay/Lesbian"> Gay/Lesbian </input> </p>
          <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "sexuality" value = "Bisexual"> Bisexual </input> </p>
          <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "sexuality" value = "Queer"> Queer </input> </p>
          <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "sexuality" value = "Intersex"> Intersex </input> </p>
          <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "sexuality" value = "Asexual"> Asexual </input> </p>
        </ul>

        <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> Religion </p>
        <ul>
          <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "religion" value = "Athiest"> Athiest </input> </p>
          <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "religion" value = "Hindu"> Hinduism </input> </p>
          <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "religion" value = "Islam"> Islam </input> </p>
          <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "Religion" value = "Christianity"> Christianity </input> </p>
          <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "religion" value = "Agnostic"> Agnostic </input> </p>
          <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "religion" value = "Buddhism"> Buddhism </input> </p>
          <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "religion" value = "Judaism"> Judaism </input> </p>
          <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "religion" value = "Sikhism"> Sikhism </input> </p>

        </ul>

      <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="submit" value = "value"/> </p>
    </form>

    {/* <!-- FOOTER --> */}
    <div class="container">
      <footer class="py-3 my-4">
        <ul class="nav justify-content-center border-bottom pb-3 mb-3">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="home.html" class="nav-link px-2 text-body-secondary"
              >Home</a>
          </li>
            <a href="{{ url_for('trending')}}" class="nav-link px-2 text-body-secondary"

              >Trending</a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">

            <a href="{{ url_for('response')}}" class="nav-link px-2 text-body-secondary"
              >Book Lists</a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="{{ url_for('questions')}}" class="nav-link px-2 text-body-secondary"
              >Q&A</a
              >
          </li>
        </ul>
        <p class="text-center text-body-secondary">© Book Website's name</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
     
    {/* <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script> */}
    </div>
   );
}
); }

export default Questions
```

Comment: Do you have link to the Hackathon challenge? You are also missing a `</footer>` closer

Answer (score 1):

Okay there is WAY TOO MUCH wrongs in this code... the tags are all over the place. I don't really understand the structure you're trying to get, like why there's a `<form>` in an unordered list (`<ul>`), why there are two `<footer>` tags on the page, but I've tried to redo most of it so it can be better in ways it can be...

So first, your code, with added notes as comments, so you'll know where the issues were and what I changed.

```
import React from "react" import Navbar from "./navbar" // import Footer from "./footer"

function Questions(){ return ( {/* */}

// FIRST OFF, THE ENTIRE FUNCTIONAL COMPONENT'S JSX IS SUPPOSED TO BE CONTAINED IN ONE TAG. NO SIBLINGS. JUST PARENT AND CHILDREN

    {/* <!-- Navigation Bar --> */}
    <Navbar/> 

<div class="container">
  <footer class="py-3 my-4">
    <ul class="nav justify-content-center border-bottom pb-3 mb-3">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="{{ url_for('home')}}" class="nav-link px-2 text-body-secondary" 

        // YOU DIDN'T CLOSE THIS <a> TAG 
        // ALSO, I AM GOING TO BELIEVE EVERYTHING ABOVE THIS, UP TO THE <footer> TAG IS A MISTAKE, CAUSE IT HAS A FOOTER AT THE TOP OF THE PAGE AND THERE IS A SIMILAR NOT-CUT-OFF VERSION AT THE BOTTOM OF THE PAGE, SO I'LL JUST SCRAPE IT OFF

<form action="#" method = "post">

  {/* <!-- Asks for name of the person --> */}
  <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> name </p>
  <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="text" name = "name"> </input> </p>
  {/* BEST PRACTICE TO USE <label>s, NOT <p>s, AND THEN LINK THEM TO THE INPUT (WHICH IS SELF-CLOSING i.e: <input />) USING THE INPUT'S IDs AND THE LABEL'S for */}


  <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> Race </p>
    <ul>
      <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "race" value = "Black"> Black </input> </p>
      <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "race" value =  "East_Asian"> East Asian </input> </p>
      <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "race" value = "Latinx"> Latinx </input> </p>
      <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "race" value = "South_Asian"> South Asian </input> </p>
      <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "race" value = "South_Asian"> South Asian </input> </p>
      <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "race" value = "White"> White </input> </p>
    </ul>

    <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> Gender </p>
    <ul>
      <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "gender" value = "Male"> Male </input> </p>
      <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "gender" value = "Female"> Female </input> </p>
      <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "gender" value = "Non-binary"> Non-binary </input> </p>
    </ul>

    <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> Sexuality </p>
    <ul>
      <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "sexuality" value = "Gay/Lesbian"> Gay/Lesbian </input> </p>
      <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "sexuality" value = "Bisexual"> Bisexual </input> </p>
      <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "sexuality" value = "Queer"> Queer </input> </p>
      <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "sexuality" value = "Intersex"> Intersex </input> </p>
      <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "sexuality" value = "Asexual"> Asexual </input> </p>
    </ul>

    <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> Religion </p>
    <ul>
      <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "religion" value = "Athiest"> Athiest </input> </p>
      <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "religion" value = "Hindu"> Hinduism </input> </p>
      <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "religion" value = "Islam"> Islam </input> </p>
      <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "Religion" value = "Christianity"> Christianity </input> </p>
      <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "religion" value = "Agnostic"> Agnostic </input> </p>
      <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "religion" value = "Buddhism"> Buddhism </input> </p>
      <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "religion" value = "Judaism"> Judaism </input> </p>
      <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="checkbox" name = "religion" value = "Sikhism"> Sikhism </input> </p>

    </ul>

  <p style = "margin-left: 50px;"> <input type="submit" value = "value"/> </p>

  {/* ONCE AGAIN, INPUTS ARE SELF CLOSING, I THINK YOU MEANT TO USE PLACEHOLDERS NOT WHAT YOU DID UP THERE. ALSO, ALL THOSE <p style = "margin-left: 50px;">S WERE REALLY UNNECESSARY AND COULD'VE BEEN DONE WITH DIVs THAT ARE STYLED BY A CERTAIN CLASS CONTROL IN CSS. */}
  {/* There were two South Asian in the race section, so I removed one */}

</form>

{/* <!-- FOOTER --> */}
<div class="container">
  <footer class="py-3 my-4">
    <ul class="nav justify-content-center border-bottom pb-3 mb-3">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="home.html" class="nav-link px-2 text-body-secondary"
          >Home</a>
      </li>
        <a href="{{ url_for('trending')}}" class="nav-link px-2 text-body-secondary"

          >Trending</a
        >
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">

        <a href="{{ url_for('response')}}" class="nav-link px-2 text-body-secondary"
          >Book Lists</a
        >
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="{{ url_for('questions')}}" class="nav-link px-2 text-body-secondary"
          >Q&A</a
          >
      </li>
    </ul>
    <p class="text-center text-body-secondary">© Book Website's name</p>
    </footer>
</div>
 
{/* <script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script> */}


</div>
); }

export default Questions
```

This is how I managed to change it up, not perfect, but this should work:

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./navbar";
// import Footer from "./footer"

function Questions() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div class="container">
        <form action="#" method="post">
          {/* <!-- Asks for name of the person --> */}
          <div className="formControl">
            <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
          </div>

          <div className="formControl"> Race </div>
          <ul>
            <div className="formControl">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="race"
                value="Black"
                id="Black"
                placeholder="Black"
              />
              <label htmlFor="Black">Black</label>
            </div>
            <div className="formControl">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="race"
                value="East_Asian"
                id="EastAsian"
                placeholder="East Asian"
              />
              <label htmlFor="EastAsian">East Asian</label>
            </div>
            <div className="formControl">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="race"
                value="Latinx"
                id="Latinx"
                placeholder="Latinx"
              />
              <label htmlFor="Latinx">Latinx</label>
            </div>
            <div className="formControl">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="race"
                value="South_Asian"
                id="SouthAsian"
                placeholder="South Asian"
              />
              <label htmlFor="SouthAsian">South Asian</label>
            </div>
            <div className="formControl">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="race"
                value="White"
                id="White"
                placeholder="White"
              />
              <label htmlFor="White">White</label>
            </div>
          </ul>

          <div className="formControl"> Gender </div>
          <ul>
            <div className="formControl">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="gender"
                value="Male"
                id="Male"
                placeholder="Male"
              />
              <label htmlFor="Male">Male</label>
            </div>
            <div className="formControl">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="gender"
                value="Female"
                id="Female"
                placeholder="Female"
              />
              <label htmlFor="Female">Female</label>
            </div>
            <div className="formControl">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="gender"
                value="Non-binary"
                id="Nonbinary"
                placeholder="Non-binary"
              />
              <label htmlFor="Nonbinary">Non-binary</label>
            </div>
          </ul>

          <div className="formControl"> Sexuality </div>
          <ul>
            <div className="formControl">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="sexuality"
                value="Gay/Lesbian"
                id="GayLesbian"
                placeholder="Gay/Lesbian"
              />
              <label htmlFor="GayLesbian">Gay/Lesbian</label>
            </div>
            <div className="formControl">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="sexuality"
                value="Bisexual"
                id="Bisexual"
                placeholder="Bisexual"
              />
              <label htmlFor="Bisexual">Bisexual</label>
            </div>
            <div className="formControl">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="sexuality"
                value="Queer"
                id="Queer"
                placeholder="Queer"
              />
              <label htmlFor="Queer">Queer</label>
            </div>
            <div className="formControl">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="sexuality"
                value="Intersex"
                id="Intersex"
                placeholder="Intersex"
              />
              <label htmlFor="Intersex">Intersex</label>
            </div>
            <div className="formControl">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="sexuality"
                value="Asexual"
                id="Asexual"
                placeholder="Asexual"
              />
              <label htmlFor="Asexual">Asexual</label>
            </div>
          </ul>

          <div className="formControl"> Religion </div>
          <ul>
            <div className="formControl">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="religion"
                value="Athiest"
                id="Athiest"
                placeholder="Athiest"
              />
              <label htmlFor="Athiest">Athiest</label>
            </div>
            <div className="formControl">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="religion"
                value="Hindu"
                id="Hinduism"
                placeholder="Hinduism"
              />
              <label htmlFor="Hinduism">Hinduism</label>
            </div>
            <div className="formControl">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="religion"
                value="Islam"
                id="Islam"
                placeholder="Islam"
              />
              <label htmlFor="Islam">Islam</label>
            </div>
            <div className="formControl">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="Religion"
                value="Christianity"
                id="Christianity"
                placeholder="Christianity"
              />
              <label htmlFor="Christianity">Christianity</label>
            </div>
            <div className="formControl">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="religion"
                value="Agnostic"
                id="Agnostic"
                placeholder="Agnostic"
              />
              <label htmlFor="Agnostic">Agnostic</label>
            </div>
            <div className="formControl">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="religion"
                value="Buddhism"
                id="Buddhism"
                placeholder="Buddhism"
              />
              <label htmlFor="Buddhism">Buddhism</label>
            </div>
            <div className="formControl">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="religion"
                value="Judaism"
                id="Judaism"
                placeholder="Judaism"
              />
              <label htmlFor="Judaism">Judaism</label>
            </div>
            <div className="formControl">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="religion"
                value="Sikhism"
                id="Sikhism"
                placeholder="Sikhism"
              />
              <label htmlFor="Sikhism">Sikhism</label>
            </div>
          </ul>

          <div className="formControl">
            <input type="submit" value="value" />
          </div>
        </form>

        {/* <!-- FOOTER --> */}
        <div class="container">
          <footer class="py-3 my-4">
            <ul class="nav justify-content-center border-bottom pb-3 mb-3">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="home.html" class="nav-link px-2 text-body-secondary">
                  Home
                </a>
              </li>
              <a
                href="{{ url_for('trending')}}"
                class="nav-link px-2 text-body-secondary"
              >
                Trending
              </a>
              {/* </li> */}
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a
                  href="{{ url_for('response')}}"
                  class="nav-link px-2 text-body-secondary"
                >
                  Book Lists
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a
                  href="{{ url_for('questions')}}"
                  class="nav-link px-2 text-body-secondary"
                >
                  Q&A
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <p class="text-center text-body-secondary">© Book Website's name</p>
          </footer>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Questions;
```

Lemme know how it goes...